# Query pairs of attributes over tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables with the following schema

Table A:

```
(Id(int PK),EmployeeId(int),DepartmentId(int))
```

Table B:

```
(Id(int PK),EmployeeId(int),DepartmentId(int))
```

DepartmentId,EmployeeId have 1 to 1 mapping i.e. they create a unique pair,
I have some invalid mappings in table B for DepartmentId,EmployeeId I want to query all those Ids from Table B, where the same EmployeeId from Table A has a different Department Id in Table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
select * 
from tableb b 
Where exists (select 1 from tablea a 
              where a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId 
              and a.DepartmentId <> b.DepartmentId)
```

**Edit :** To update

```
UPDATE b
SET    b.DepartmentId = a.DepartmentId
FROM   tablea a
       INNER JOIN tableb b
               ON a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
WHERE  a.DepartmentId != b.DepartmentId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this can you suggest a SQL which updates the bad departmentId in table B by taking correct departmentId from table A

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.EmployeeId
from a
inner join b on a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
where a.DepartmentId != b.DepartmentId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this can you suggest a SQL which updates the bad departmentId in table B by taking correct departmentId from table A

Comment: UPDATE b SET DepartmentId = a.DepartmentId
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
WHERE a.DepartmentId != b.DepartmentId